Laptop can't wake up from sleep or after closing the lid: Ubuntu 22.04, Lenovo P51
I am stuck trying to get my laptop to respond after it sleeps. I have read many similar threads but none has worked. I need urgent help.
The issue started after an upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04.
Below is a picture of the screen where it gets stuck.
It hands at the "Bluetooth" messages. After about a minute it prints the other messages.
Help.

I had to downgrade my Ubuntu from 22.04 to 20.04. That "solved" the problem.
